# Are "during after school" and "after school" the same?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/will-be-doing-vs-will-do) says

> For example,:
>
> > I will walk home.
>
> and
>
> > I will be walking home.
>
> Both refer to walking home in the future, but the first statement is
>   used when referring to the next thing you are going to do i.e. during
>   after school, while the second statement can be used anytime from the
>   day before to just before going to school.

which uses the phrasing "during after school".

Does this expression make sense if I omit "during", which gets me "the next thing you are going to do after school"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of *[Afterschool](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=afterschool)* or *after-school* is more or less the literal meaning of its components; per AHD:

> *adj*
>   1. Taking place immediately following school classes: *afterschool activities*.
>   2. Of or being a program designed to provide care for and educational enhancement to children in the hours immediately following school classes.
>
> *n.*
>   An afterschool program.

Thursagen may have accidentally omitted a word, intending *during after-school hours* or *during after-school programs*, but only Thursagen would be able to say for certain.

If the phrasing was intended, then *during after school* and *after school* can indeed mean different things. In the first, *after school* refers to some set event or activity that takes place after the end of classroom instruction, which has a set start and finish time. The latter refers to any time after the end of classroom instruction.

For example, my high school's formal instruction ended at 2:05 p.m., and activities like sports practice, drama rehearsal, and so on began at 3:00 p.m. to allow for 45 minutes of study hall and 10 minutes of walking. If I told some students that I planned to walk home *during after school*, they would likely assume I meant I would walk home some time between 2:05 and 3:00p.m. If I told them I planned to walk home *after school*, then I might be walking at any time after 2:05 p.m.

I will add that *afterschool* as a noun sounds terrible to my ears, and I myself would only use it in rapid, informal speech as a shorthand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "add that afterschool" mean?

Comment: *[add](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=add): To say or write further.* [AHD]